# Getting issue with profilers on Android TV development

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

We are working on app development for Android TV.
We have started working on app performance in terms of janky frames, app startup time, UI scrolling and performance.
We have used standard tools provided by android-studio like Android profilers, perfetto by google and jankstats for measuring perfoemance.
Issues we are facing :

- Using android studio profiler makes Android TV device very slow and not able to capture proper traces
- We have also tried using emulator, but it will not give clear picture of performance
- We have also used on multiple physical devices, but does not show complete traces.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.